# Magento 1.9 module returns 404

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create my module to extend one feature in magento 1.9.1.
I don't know what I have done wrong, I used ths [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) and everything looks the same except for the name.

And another question, how to add arguments to url and route to pass them to function ?

I tried urls below :

```
http://www.example.com/Kingdom_PatterModule
http://www.example.com/patter_sendrequest/
http://www.example.com/index.php/patter_sendrequest
http://www.example.com/index.php/patter_sendrequest/index
```

My module path are:

```
local/
   Kingdom/
      /PatterModule
         /controllers
         IndexController.php
         /etc
         config.xml
```

And below my code:

My `app/etc/modules/Kingdom_PatterModule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
    <Kingdom_PatterModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Kingdom_PatterModule>
</modules>
</config>
```

My `app/code/local/Kingdom/PatterModule/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Kingdom_PatterModule>
        <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Kingdom_PatterModule>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <patter_sendrequest>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Kingdom_PatterModule</module>
                <frontName>pattermodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </patter_sendrequest>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

And My Controller `app/code/local/Kingdom/PatterModule/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php
class Kingdom_PatterModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello I'm working...';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Advise 1/ never ever close the php tag `?>` on a class. Then : your url = `the_frontname_of_your_module/your_controller_name/your_action`. `IndexController` being the default controller, it can be implicit. `indexAction`being the default action, it can be implicit. So try this http://www.example.com/pattermodule/ or http://www.example.com/pattermodule/index/ or http://www.example.com/pattermodule/index/index they should all work.

Comment: and also post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ - you may have more success getting a response

Answer (score -1):

As it seems you have not added the layout section in frontend so that it is returning 404 page on frontend

```
    <routers>
    <patter_sendrequest>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <module>Kingdom_PatterModule</module>
            <frontName>pattermodule</frontName>
        </args>
    </patter_sendrequest>
</routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <patter_sendrequest>
                <file>pattermodule.xml</file>
            </patter_sendrequest>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

After adding this code in config.xml, Write index action in the pattermodule.xml file. Please let us know if you need more clarification.

Comment: You don't need a layout for a controller to work. What would you put in this layout if your controller was API only or Ajax requested only by the way ?